# How do I encode streamable video in iOS?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-streaming

How can I encode such a stream from the phone's camera? Ultimately I would like to capture this on a server for recorded playback/streaming.

I know there are a lot of similar threads with hacky answers, but I'm looking for a better solution or even an understanding of the difference in formats.

I see a lot of articles with custom solutions like ffmpeg wrappers, but from what I understand those are CPU heavy. There are a lot of video conferencing apps - are they all using custom encoding solutions? Did apple really leave this out?

Comment: I don't know about iPhones, but a lot of cameras output mpeg-ts which can be directly save as a file. VLC will play the file no problems. A ts (transport stream) can easily be converted to anything. You will also find it to be mpeg2 format.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be do live streaming using WebRTC or similar solution to a server. This will make use of RTP/RTCP and will take care of most of the issues which occurs during live streaming. The latency will be less however this is a complex solution.

If you are looking to put something quickly and do not have lots of concerns about latency, I would suggest something like this:

1. Create small 10s clips of video in mp4 format and keep uploading the same to server using REST APIs
2. On server end, use ffmpeg/gstreamer to extract the video and create a HLS or similar stream out of it.